# LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, left-join

Using extension syntax I'm trying to create a left-join using LINQ on two lists that I have. The following is from the Microsoft help but I've modified it to show that the pets list has no elements. What I'm ending up with is a list of 0 elements. I assume that this is because an inner-join is taking place. What I want to end up with is a list of 3 elements (the 3 Person objects) with null data filled in for the missing elements. i.e. a Left-Join. Is this possible?

```
Person magnus = new Person { Name = "Hedlund, Magnus" };
Person terry = new Person { Name = "Adams, Terry" };
Person charlotte = new Person { Name = "Weiss, Charlotte" };

//Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
//Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
//Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
//Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte };
//List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, daisy };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>();

// Create a list of Person-Pet pairs where 
// each element is an anonymous type that contains a
// Pet's name and the name of the Person that owns the Pet.
var query =
    people.Join(pets,
                person => person,
                pet => pet.Owner,
                (person, pet) =>
                    new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pet.Name }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think if you want to use extension methods you need to use the [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534805.aspx)

```
var query =
    people.GroupJoin(pets,
                     person => person,
                     pet => pet.Owner,
                     (person, petCollection) =>
                        new { OwnerName = person.Name,
                              Pet = PetCollection.Select( p => p.Name )
                                                 .DefaultIfEmpty() }
                    ).ToList();
```

You may have to play around with the selection expression.  I'm not sure it would give you want you want in the case where you have a 1-to-many relationship.

I think it's a little easier with the LINQ Query syntax

```
var query = (from person in context.People
             join pet in context.Pets on person equals pet.Owner
             into tempPets
             from pets in tempPets.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pets.Name })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: wohoo :) Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I did not know you could get .ToList() by putting brackets around the query method, thanks!

Comment: Please do not call the LINQ declarative query syntax "LINQ syntax". They are both "LINQ syntax". The proper naming is "Query Syntax" vs "Method Syntax". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: The improper naming of the latter is "yoda-style syntax".

Answer (score 17):

You need to get the joined objects into a set and then apply DefaultIfEmpty as JPunyon said:

```
Person magnus = new Person { Name = "Hedlund, Magnus" };
Person terry = new Person { Name = "Adams, Terry" };
Person charlotte = new Person { Name = "Weiss, Charlotte" };

Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte };
List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>{barley};

var results =
    from person in people
    join pet in pets on person.Name equals pet.Owner.Name into ownedPets
    from ownedPet in ownedPets.DefaultIfEmpty(new Pet())
    orderby person.Name
    select new { OwnerName = person.Name, ownedPet.Name };


foreach (var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        String.Format("{0,-25} has {1}", item.OwnerName, item.Name ) );
}
```

Outputs:

```
Adams, Terry              has Barley
Hedlund, Magnus           has
Weiss, Charlotte          has
```

Comment: Thanks Gishu - very useful info.

Comment: I think you could replace the 2 lines: `join pet...` and `from ownedPet...` with the single line: `from pet in pets.Where(x => person.Name == x.Owner.Name).DefaultIfEmpty()`

Answer (score 5):

I the following error message when faced this same problem:

**The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'.**

Solved when I used the same property name, it worked.

(...)

```
join enderecoST in db.PessoaEnderecos on 
    new 
      {  
         CD_PESSOA          = nf.CD_PESSOA_ST, 
         CD_ENDERECO_PESSOA = nf.CD_ENDERECO_PESSOA_ST 
      } equals 
    new 
    { 
         enderecoST.CD_PESSOA, 
         enderecoST.CD_ENDERECO_PESSOA 
    } into eST
```

(...)

Comment: +1 for this. I sat staring at my code for 15 minutes, trying to understand why 2 anonymous classes with the same types weren't the same. Then I added explicit property names...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good blog post that's just been posted by Fabrice (author of LINQ in Action) which covers the material in the question that I asked. I'm putting it here for reference as readers of the question will find this useful.

[Converting LINQ queries from query syntax to method/operator syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2009/02/06/converting-linq-queries-from-query-syntax-to-method-operator-syntax.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Left joins in LINQ are possible with the DefaultIfEmpty() method.  I don't have the exact syntax for your case though...

Actually I think if you just change pets to pets.DefaultIfEmpty() in the query it might work...

EDIT:  I really shouldn't answer things when its late...

Answer (score 0):

If you actually have a database, this is the most-simple way:

```
var lsPetOwners = ( from person in context.People
                    from pets in context.Pets
                        .Where(mypet => mypet.Owner == person.ID) 
                        .DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { OwnerName = person.Name, Pet = pets.Name }
                   ).ToList();
```