# Can't get Left JOIN linq query to work!

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've been looking at the following post and trying to apply it to mine but with no luck:
[LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join)

I have the query below that returns 0 records everytime I run it:

```
        var tasks = from tt in d.luProjectTaskTypes
                    join cbt in d.CostByTasks
                      on tt.ProjectTaskTypeID equals cbt.ProjectTaskTypeID into temp
                    from cbt in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where cbt.ProposalID == Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"])  || cbt.ProposalID == null
                    select new
                    {
                        ProposalId = (cbt.ProposalID == null ? Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) : cbt.ProposalID),
                        TaskId = tt.ProjectTaskTypeID,
                        CostByTaskId = (cbt.CostByTaskID == null ? 0 : cbt.CostByTaskID),
                        TypeOfWork = tt.ProjectTaskType,
                        AmountRequested = (cbt.AmountRequested == null ? 0 : cbt.AmountRequested),
                        CostShare = (cbt.CostShareAmount == null ? 0 : cbt.CostShareAmount)
                    };
```

Where `luProjectTaskTypes` is a lookup table that has a list of options.  I want one record returned for each entry in this table regardless of whether it has a match in `CostByTasks` but I always get 0.  What am I doing wrong?!

**UPDATE:**

This is the SQL it is generating-

```
SELECT 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t1].[ProposalID]) IS NULL THEN @p1
        ELSE [t1].[ProposalID]
     END) AS [ProposalId], [t0].[ProjectTaskTypeID] AS [TaskId], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN ([t1].[CostByTaskID]) IS NULL THEN @p2
        ELSE [t1].[CostByTaskID]
     END) AS [CostByTaskId], [t0].[ProjectTaskType] AS [TypeOfWork], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t1].[AmountRequested] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),@p3)
       ELSE CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),[t1].[AmountRequested])
     END) AS [AmountRequested], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t1].[CostShareAmount] IS NULL THEN CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),@p4)
        ELSE CONVERT(Decimal(33,4),[t1].[CostShareAmount])
     END) AS [CostShare]
FROM [frgprop].[luProjectTaskType] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [frgprop].[CostByTask] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProjectTaskTypeID] = [t1].[ProjectTaskTypeID]
WHERE ([t1].[ProposalID] = @p0) OR (([t1].[ProposalID]) IS NULL)
```

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: As you can see, it's definitely generating a LEFT JOIN... so I suggest you start hacking at the SQL itself until that produces what you want, and then try to convert that back into LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this'll help, but you could try moving your where clause into the join -

```
var tasks = from tt in d.luProjectTaskTypes
            join cbt in d.CostByTasks
              on new {ptid = tt.ProjectTaskTypeID,  pid = cbt.ProposalID } equals new { ptid = cbt.ProjectTaskTypeID, pid = Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"] } into temp
            from cbt in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
                ProposalId = (cbt.ProposalID == null ? Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) : cbt.ProposalID),
                TaskId = tt.ProjectTaskTypeID,
                CostByTaskId = (cbt.CostByTaskID == null ? 0 : cbt.CostByTaskID),
                TypeOfWork = tt.ProjectTaskType,
                AmountRequested = (cbt.AmountRequested == null ? 0 : cbt.AmountRequested),
                CostShare = (cbt.CostShareAmount == null ? 0 : cbt.CostShareAmount)
            };
```

You would need to worry about checking for `cbt.ProposalID == null` and It should produce this sql instead -

```
 ...   FROM [frgprop].[luProjectTaskType] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [frgprop].[CostByTask] AS [t1] ON [t0].[ProjectTaskTypeID] = [t1].[ProjectTaskTypeID] AND [t1].[ProposalID] = @p0
```

**UPDATE:**
Below is the updated version that compiles.  A few minor changes got it working.

```
var tasks = from tt in d.luProjectTaskTypes
                        join cbt in d.CostByTasks
                          on new {tt.ProjectTaskTypeID, ProposalID = Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) } equals new {cbt.ProjectTaskTypeID, cbt.ProposalID} into temp
                        from cbt in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            ProposalId = (cbt.ProposalID == null ? Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) : cbt.ProposalID),
                            TaskId = tt.ProjectTaskTypeID,
                            CostByTaskId = (cbt.CostByTaskID == null ? 0 : cbt.CostByTaskID),
                            TypeOfWork = tt.ProjectTaskType,
                            AmountRequested = (cbt.AmountRequested == null ? 0 : cbt.AmountRequested),
                            CostShare = (cbt.CostShareAmount == null ? 0 : cbt.CostShareAmount)
                        };
```

Comment: Looks like you have the right idea but it doesn't quite compile.  I went ahead and added a post of my own with working changes for future users.

Comment: That's fine - just let me know where the compilation error is an i can fix it here, that way there's no duplicate answer and the correct answer gets credit.  I wasn't going to check for compilation errors since setting up the types would be overkill on my part.  Or you could even edit it yourself since you have over 2000 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the WHERE clause

When you LEFT JOIN a table, that's fine, but if you set criteria on the LEFT-JOINED table, it basically turns it into an INNER JOIN.  You should allow for Nulls to get past this.

```
where cbt.ProposalID == Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) OR cbt.ProposalID is NULL
```

I'm not sure how about the is NULL syntax -- maybe have to be `db.null(field)`, etc. -- you'll have to check on that; but the concept is valid.

Comment: Also -- you need to turn it back into a *left* join.

Comment: I assume you mean add `|| cbt.ProposalID == null`.  I did this and still no records.  I've updated my LINQ query to reflect this change, is that what you meant?

Comment: Note that a simpler way to do this would be to put the where clause into the join: "from cbt in d.CostByTasks.Where(x => x.ProposalId == ...)"

Comment: Arg... yes -- that's what I meant.  I see this problem all the time in regular SQL queries.  OK -- still looking.  I guess I'd next try pulling the WHERE clause off, to see if your left join is working as it should -- at least that could help narrow it down.

Comment: unfortunately it pulls a bunch of records that i don't want if I take off the `WHERE` clause.  I'm playing with the SQL now to see if I can resolve the issue, let me know if you find anything.

Comment: Try writing the null sentence like this:
where cbt.ProposalID != null ? Convert.ToInt32(this.StateItems["PropNumber"]) : null

Comment: I'd also recommend doing a response.write on your this.StateItems["PropNumber"], just to make sure the value you *think* is in there really is...