# left join in LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, left-join

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join)

How can i implement left join in LINQ?

plz provide me sample code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join) - The whole related sidebar is already filled with answers.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on [Left Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)