# Proper Join/GroupJoin implementation

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have been trying to work with the Join and GroupJoin method. The problem seems simple. Given `TableA` and `TableB` as datamaps such that:

```
class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public Table<tblA> TableA;
    public Table<tblB> TableB;
}
```

...I am using `TableA` as my primary table and want to join on one field, `CustomerID` in `TableB` to retrieve `[TableB].[LastName]`.

Should not be difficult, except that I am having difficulty getting results to work properly. TableA has records that I want regardless of a matching CustomerID in TableB. Sounds like a left join - so, reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join), I mimicked what @tvanfosson suggested:

```
// appropriately rewritten for my needs - so I thought...
private static IQueryable GetRecordsByView1(IQueryable<tblA> source)
{
    var records = source.GroupJoin(myContext.TableB,
                  info => info.CustomerID,
                  owner => owner.CustomerID,
                  (info, owner) => new
                  {
                      info.CustomerID,
                      Owner = owner.Select(o => o.LastName).DefaultIfEmpty(),
                      Store = info.Store,
                  })
                  .Select(record => new
                  {
                      record.CustomerID,
                      record.Owner,
                      record.Store,
                  });

    return records;
}
```

`source` is dynamic, such that one method builds a dynamic query:

```
public static void QueryStores()
{
    IQueryable<tblA> source = myContext.TableA;

    if (criteriaA)
        source = source.Where(// something);

    if (criteriaB)
        source = source.Where(// something);

    // after processing criteria logic, determine type of view
    switch (byView)
    {
        case View1:
        {
            source = GetRecordsByView1(source);
            break;
        }

        //other case blocks
    }

    myGridView.DataSource = source;
}
```

The problem: I am receiving the following error:

> Could not format node 'OptionalValue'
>   for execution as SQL.

I believe it is in the following line of code:

```
Owner = owner.Select(o => o.LastName).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have to write `GroupJoin` as an extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First...@Brian got me started on the right track. Here is the solution:

```
var records = source
              .GroupJoin(myContext.TableB,
              info => info.CustomerID,
              owner => owner.CustomerID,
              (info, owner) => new
              {
                  info,
                  Owner = owner.Select(o => o.LastName).First()
              })
              .Select(record => new
              {
                  record.info.CustomerID,
                  record.Owner,
                  record.info.Store
              });
```

This provides me with the exact results desired...

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that `Owner = owner.Select(o => o.LastName).DefaultIfEmpty()` is the line causing your problems. The best workaround that I have come up with is something like this:

```
var records = source.GroupJoin(myContext.TableB,
                  info => info.CustomerID,
                  owner => owner.CustomerID,
                  (info, owner) => new { info, owner }).ToList();
records.Select(x => new
                  {
                      x.info.CustomerID,
                      Owner = x.owner.First() == null ? new string[] {} : x.owner.Select(o => o.LastName).ToArray(),
                      Store = x.info.Store,
                  })
                  .Select(record => new
                  {
                      record.CustomerID,
                      record.Owner,
                      record.Store,
                  });
```

It certainly isn't ideal (you have to materialize the groupjoin with 'ToList'), and there might be a better solution, but that has worked for me.  You might have to play around a bit to get it to work just right for you, but I hope this helps you along your way.

Comment: This looks promising. I did see where it looks like there is just a failure to materialize the data - I'm beginning to understand that. After removing `DefaultIfEmpty()`, the query goes through but the Owner result is blank. I stepped into the results and the Owner last name is in there, but buried. So I know I'm close...thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this left outer join example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx

The relevant sample:

```
var query = from person in people
join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) }
```

You can join the results into gj, then use DefaultIfEmpty to create the outer join situation, and still get the results you want.

Someone else got a similar error using DefaultIfEmpty here:
[Max or Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default)
http://blog.appelgren.org/2008/05/15/linq-to-sql-aggregates-and-empty-results/

HTH.

Comment: The problem is that I have to write my `Join` as an extension method. I cannot write as LINQ statement.