# Convert SQL Left Join to Linq

Tags: .net, sql, linq

I'm having some difficulty converting this SQL Statement to LINQ:

```
Declare @ind date, @outd date
set @ind = '2012-03-17'
set @outd = '2012-03-18'

SELECT k.id
FROM Kennels k
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM Reservations 
            WHERE (DateIn >= @ind and DateIn < @outd) or  (DateOut > @ind and DateOut <= @outd)) r ON k.id = r.Kennel_ID
WHERE r.kennel_id is null
```

Linq:

```
Dim available = From k In Kennels _
                    Group Join r In db.Reservations.Where(Function(fx) (fx.DateIn >= Date_From And fx.DateIn < Date_To) Or (fx.DateOut > Date_From And fx.DateOut <= Date_To)) On k Equals r.Kennel Into Group _
                    From r In Group.DefaultIfEmpty
                    Where r.Kennel.ID Is Nothing
                    Select k
```

The problem with my Linq statement is when r is nothing, the "Where r.Kennel.ID" part of the query falls over.

I'd appreciate some help rewriting this query!

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `Where r.Kennel.ID Is Nothing` to `Where r Is Nothing`

But in c# I would write

```
var available =
    from k in db.Kennels
    where !k.Reservations.Any(r => r.DateIn >= Date_From && r.DateIn < Date_To) || (r.DateOut > Date_From && r.DateOut <= Date_To)
    select k;
```

as I find it easier to read.
Sorry for my VB beeing a bit rusty, but I think you can translate it easily (`||` is `Or`, `&&` is `And` and `!` is `Not`)

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I used a combination of this and my existing query and got it to work. It was essentially the r is nothing which got it.