# select values tolist() when orderby distinct date

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to order the selected values by ascending distinct date.

For example i have these values in my database.

```
ID | Value | Date 
 1 | 35    | 2012/01/20
 2 | 0     | 2012/01/20
 3 | 10    | 2012/02/01
 4 | 0     | 2012/02/01
 5 | 0     | 2012/03/01
 6 | 0     | 2012/03/01
```

Since ID 1 has a value on the 20th of January and ID 3 has a value on the 1st of February i want these two dates to be selected to my list of distinct date values. But for ID 5 and 6 both have value 0. So if value is 0 i also want the value 0 to be added.

Now my linqquery looks like this

```
        var totalHours = (from u in context.Users
                          join r in context.Reports on u.Id equals r.UserId
                          join w in context.Weeks on r.Id equals w.ReportId
                          join d in context.Days on w.DayId equals d.Id
                          orderby d.Date ascending
                          where r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek)
                          select d.Hour).ToList();
```

But this query of course gives me 35,0,10,0,0,0 as result.
Though I want it to give me 35,10,0

I dont want do pick out distinct values, say if February 1st and February 2nd has the same values. I want both these values to be added.

Comment: are you want to group and order your list by value?

Comment: @rickard - so if there is a value other than 0 (id 1) and then another value that is 0 (id 2) you want just the non zero one ? Could it happen that id 1 = 35, id 2 = 50 ? If so, do you want both ?

Comment: @Joanna if value is equal for the same date (in this case 0) i want also the value 0 to be added to the list().

Comment: @Joanna no, that cant happen. But it can happend that both values are 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to first select what you need from the first query:

```
 var totalHours = (from u in context.Users
                          join r in context.Reports on u.Id equals r.UserId
                          join w in context.Weeks on r.Id equals w.ReportId
                          join d in context.Days on w.DayId equals d.Id
                          orderby d.Date ascending
                          where r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek)
                          select new {id = r.UserId, hour = d.Hour, date = d.Date}).ToList();
```

In the above I assumed that d.Hour corresponds to the `Value` field in your example.

Then group by date, order by hour descending and select the first item from each group:

```
var distinctValues = totalHours
                .GroupBy(th => th.Date)
                .OrderByDescending(v => v.Max(o => o.Hour))
                .Select(g => g.First());
```

**UPDATE**

To return just the list of integers for the Hour property use this instead of the above statement:

```
 var distinctValues = totalHours
                .GroupBy(th => th.Date)
                .OrderByDescending(v => v.Max(o => o.Hour))
                .Select(g => g.First().Hour)
                .ToList();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Can you try this ?

```
var distinctValues = totalHours
                .GroupBy(th => th.Date)
                .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(e => e.Hour))
                .Select(g => g.First().Hour)
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Do i want to return disticntValues after i have done these steps? When i try to i get this error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: And if i put .ToList() after .Select(g => g.First()).ToList(); i get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'"

Comment: @rickard - Yes, the `distinctValues` should be what you are looking for. If you want just one property from the anonymous type then change the last line to `.Select(g => g.First().Hour)` (or any other property you need). The ToList() call should work just fine then and give you a list of `int`s - see the update

Comment: Fabulous!! It's working, i just had to remove .OrderbyDescdending( Max) since i dont want to order it by highest value! Thank you

Comment: @rickard - I believe there's a misunderstanding - the `OrderByDescending` won't order the values in your resulting list of integers. It's necessary to get the highest value within the group - i.e. if you had a group with `{0, 35}` and the 0 was the first value, without the `OrderByDescending` you would get the zero instead of 35 in the resulting list. So I would recomment putting the ordering back in.

Comment: @rickard - You're right. See update 2 - I think this should do it.

Comment: the problem with using OrderByDescending is that the result is ordered by highest value, instead of date. Maybe i am missing something. And if i remove the `OrderByDescending` the problem is, as you are saying the result returns `{0, 35}` the 0 value

Comment: @rickard - you mean the update2 version or the previous one ?

Comment: sorry u answeared before i made my correction. I just tried the update2 version. AND.... wait for it.... It works perfectly!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you want it grouped on date with the hours aggregated. If so would it be something like this maybe?

```
 var totalHours = (from u in context.Users                           
join r in context.Reports on u.Id equals r.UserId                           
join w in context.Weeks on r.Id equals w.ReportId                           
join d in context.Days on w.DayId equals d.Id                           
orderby d.Date ascending                           
where r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek)                           
).GroupBy(n => n.Date).Select(n => new { Date = n.Key, Hour = Sum(x => x.Hour) }).ToList();
```

Just to explain

```
.GroupBy(n => n.Date)
```

Will group the results by the date so you will get a distinct row per date

```
.Select(n => new { Date = n.Key, Hour = Sum(x => x.Hour) })
```

will select and shape the result. We are shaping into a new object. `n.Key` is the key that the group by worked on so this will be `Date`. The second property is the aggregate of the hours so each distinct date will have it's hours summed. We are using the `new` keyword so the results are put into a new custom object. We have defined the names of the properties of the new object so there will be two - `Date` and `Hour`

Comment: Yes, it is a result like that i am after. But i dont understand everything in this code and it gives me errors so i'm not able to test it correctly.

Comment: "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" and "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'" and "The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'."

Comment: OK - getting the group by to work with joins is the wrinkle. This post gives pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join. If i get time I will rework

Comment: Working with .GroupBy(n => ) does not give me anything on n.Date

Comment: With a few correction this code now only gives me one errorcode "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<int>'"

Comment: Change the last clause to select new { Hour = grouped.Sum(x => x.Hour) }).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
 var totalHours = (from u in context.Users
                          join r in context.Reports on u.Id equals r.UserId
                          join w in context.Weeks on r.Id equals w.ReportId
                          join d in context.Days on w.DayId equals d.Id
                          orderby d.Date ascending
                          where r.weekNr.Equals(currentWeek)
                          select d.Hour).Distinct().OrderByDescending( n => n ).ToList();
```

Comment: I dont want to pick out distinct values, only distinct date. So if multiple dates, say 1 of february and 2 of february has same value. This method only give me one of these days.