# Any way to add a property using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

So I have this list, it returns an ID and a thumbnail. ex. `List<PersonPicture>`
and I have this list, `List<Person>` which has a property named "picture" in it.
Is there anyway that I can merge this two properties and add the `List<PersonPicture>` to the property named "picture" in it and base this via the ID since they have the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Better if you declare your class in here, and show your tried code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous object for this, below an example:

```
List<PersonPicture> pictures = LoadPictures();
List<Person> persons = LoadPersons();

var result = persons.Select(pers => new
{
  Id = pers.Id,
  Name = pers.Name,
  Picture = pictures.Where(pic => pic.PersId == pers.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .Thumbnail
};
```

Another solution is to use a Join:

```
var result = persons.Join(pictures, 
  pers => pers.Id, 
  pic => pic.PersId,
  (pers, pic) => { 
    return new
    {
      Id = pers.Id,
      Name = pers.Name,
      Picture = pic.Thumbnail
    };
  });
```

Comment: why is foreach faster on execution than this? I am trying to optimize my foreach statement and linq did not help.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ isn't quite designed for modifying existing collections like this, but you can do it:

```
foreach (tup in people
    .Join(
        picture,
        person => person.ID,
        picture => picture.ID,
        Tuple.Create
    ))
{
    tup.Item1.Picture = tup.Item2;
}
```

EDIT: Note that this will produce unpredictable results if a person has more than one picture. Is this a possibility, and how should it be dealt with?

Comment: That's a nifty usage of `Tuple.Create` instead of anonymous objects, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a [Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/525241/920359) or the [Zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5122767/920359) operator in linq. These links will take you to questions about the syntax of using both of them. Basically the Join just adds the two lists together based on a key just like in SQL and the Zip merges the two lists by matching the position of each element in each list..

Answer (score 0):

You want to *join* the two lists based on a shared key -- the ID.

Basically, you want to use the `Join` operator in LINQ to find pairs of `Person` and `PersonPicture` that match the same ID:

```
    persons.Join(pictures, // join these two lists 
        person => person.Id, // extract key from person
        personPicture => personPicture.PersonId, // extract key from picture
        (person, personPicture) => ??? // do something with each matching pair
```

The question you now face is what to do with each matching pair; `Join` lets you supply a delegate that takes a matching pair and returns something else, and the result of the Join operation will be a list of those 'something else's produced from each of the matching pairs.

Your problem is that you want to take each pair and do something with it -- specifically, you want to copy the picture from the `PersonPicture` object to the `Person` object. Since LINQ is all about finding data but not modifying it, this is not trivial.

You can do this in two ways. One is to create a temporary object from each pair, and then iterate over that and do your thing:

```
    var pairs = persons.Join(pictures, 
        person => person.Id, 
        personPicture => personPicture.PersonId,
        (person, personPicture) => new { person, personPicture };

    foreach (var pair in pairs) 
        pair.person.Picture = pair.personPicture.Thumbnail;
```

(You can use a Tuple instead of a temporary object, as was suggested in another answer).

This works, but seems clumsy because of the temporary object (be it an anonymous object or a tuple).

Alternatively, you can do the assignment right inside the delegate, and return the Person object itself, since you're done with the PersonPicture object:

```
    var personsWithPicturesPopulated = persons.Join(pictures, 
        person => person.Id, 
        personPicture => personPicture.PersonId,
        (person, personPicture) => { 
             person.Picture = personPicture.Thumbnail; 
             return person;
        });
```

This has the added bonus of giving you the list of persons for which you found a match in the `personPictures` list, omitting the ones without a match; this is sometimes exactly what you need (and other times it isn't, in which case you can discard the result of the join).

Comment: why is foreach faster on execution than this? I am trying to optimize my foreach statement and linq did not help.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. What are you `foreach`-ing over which is faster? If you're doing a nested foreach (e.g. foreach person, foreach personPicture, if p.id==pp.id then p.picture=pp.picture) then theoretically for large lists it should be **slower** than using Join -- computationally speaking, nested foreach is O(n*m) while Join is O(n+m) since it uses a hash table under the hood. For small lists, nested foreach might be slightly faster due to less overhead, but this difference should be negligible.

Comment: Maybe you could post your `foreach` solution and ask why it's faster as an edit to this question (or maybe as a new one)?