# how to do left join in lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

```
    var item= (from t1 in _dbEntities.PurchaseSales
                join t2 in _dbEntities.ItemTypes on t1.ItemTypeID equals t2.ID
                where t2.ID.Equals(null)
               select t2).ToList();
```

how to do left join in it

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
var item= (from t1 in _dbEntities.PurchaseSales
                join t2 in _dbEntities.ItemTypes on t1.ItemTypeID equals t2.ID into t
                from l in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where l == null
               select t1).ToList();
```