# multi left outer join query

Tags: linq, left-join

I'm searching for Linq left outer join query syntax, and I'm struggling to find a good answer for that. My specific SQL query is:

```
Select tblBpGood.barcode, tblBPGood.Code, Name, RetailPrice, GoodGroupID, tblBPGoodGroupL.Description, 
  PurchaseUnitTypeID, SalesUnitTypeID, tblBPUnitTypeL.Description as SalesUnitType, 
  tblBPUnitTypeL_1.Description as PurchaseUnitType 
from tblBPGood 
left outer join tblBPGoodGroupL 
on tblBPGood.GoodGroupID = tblBPGoodGroupL.ID  
left outer join tblBPUnitTypeL 
on tblBPGood.SalesUnitTypeID = tblBPUnitTypeL.id  
left outer join tblBPUnitTypeL as tblBPUnitTypeL_1 
on tblBPGood.PurchaseUnitTypeID = tblBPUnitTypeL_1.id
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ Inner-Join vs Left-Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525194/linq-inner-join-vs-left-join)

Comment: In addition check this [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2994/left-right-and-cross-outer-join#t=201608081950183524094)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.